# The right way to control EN pin of TPS63806 using STM32 MCU

Tags: power, buck-boost

I have a 3.3v STM32L4 MCU powered by it's own supply and an external circuit powered by a buck-boost TPS63806. The power source is a 18650 battery, providing from 2.8-4.2 volts.

I want to turn on and off the TPS63806 using a digital pin of the MCU connected to EN pin of the converter and I would like to know the right way of doing that. For now, I have 2 options:

1. Use a 2N7002 FET (as in the attached circuit). I have no idea how to calculate the value of R17.
2. Use a voltage divider with 10 and 15 kOhms (or a single resistor) between EN and the PIN of the MCU, but I need to get about 2.5 volts on the EN pin. Could I also use 100 and 150kOms?

[image: design]

Answer (score 0):

Neither makes sense.

Directly connect your MCU output to the enable pin.

Your MCU produces ca 0V in LOW output state and ca 3.3 V in HIGH output state.

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63806.pdf?ts=1610117349968) of your TPS clearly says the on/off threshold voltage is somewhere around 1 to 1.1 V. So, with your GPIO low you're solidly below that, and with its high solidly above it. All good!

So, nothing needed. Your voltage divider would only make sense if you needed a lower voltage, your MOSFET only if.. no, it simply doesn't make sense, and both ideas also seem to be designed to do the exact opposite of each other!

Also, I do hope your lithium cell has battery protection built in! You don't want to deep-discharge it (which you can definitely do this way), as that will render the battery useless, and you definitely don't want to accidentially short-circuit it (as that also renders the battery useless, but potentially also makes it an explosive device).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this was the first thing I though, but, if I correctly understood the datasheet (9.3.2 on page 11), the enable pin can also be used with an external voltage divider to set a user-defined minimum supply voltage. So, if I apply 3.3v to enable pin and the battery goes down to 3 volts, the module will be off. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why would you want to set that? Simply use your microcontroller to sense the supply voltage (I think it even has a dedicated ADC channel for that!) and don't enable it if the battery voltage is too low... Also, at 3.3V or 3V your lithium battery is already irreparably damaged. Far, far too low.

Comment: I don't really want to set that, it is how the module works. What I'm saying is if I'm supplying a 3.3v to the enable pin, that means that the VIN must be higher or equal to 3.3v. I do have a BMS (which is not on the diagram for simplicity). But 18650 can go safely up to 3v from what I know. So the Ideal situation is to have 3volts on the EN pin, and if the battery goes lower, the module will shut down (if BMS does not cut the power before).

Comment: but VIN **is** higher, unless your battery is already broken.

Comment: (A lithium battery should *really* not drop below ca 3.6 V)

Comment: Thank you. I will attach the EN pin directly to MCU pin.